# Angular 7 Google Recaptcha v 2 Error when build

Tags: angular, recaptcha

my angular app is version 7

i install recaptcha from npm

```
npm i ng-recaptcha
```

default version is 8.0.1

when i use `ng serve` for debug my app run

but when use `ng build --prod` i get error and my app not build

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-recaptcha/fesm5/ng-recaptcha.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:77:21)
    at visitNodes (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16144:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16370:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16265:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16322:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16333:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16229:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNodes (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16144:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16379:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16135:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (E:\sheedRepository-Web\ControlPanel\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:16377:21)
```

i think maybe install last version so install 7,6,5,4 but again get error  on build.